# Adding recors in MySql

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I want to add some 1000 records into my table for creating a database. Inserting each record manually is not at all practical. Is there a proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you can insert multiple rows with a single insert statement.

```
insert into table values (data-row-1), (data-row-2), (data-row-3)
```

If you run a `mysqldump` on your database, you will see that this is what the output does.

The `insert` is then run as a single "transaction", so it's much, much faster than running 1000 individual `inserts`